# Clear check mark and dropdowns when opposite radio button is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I clear the checkmark in my checkbox when clicking on the opposite radio button? For some reason I cannot get it to clear will someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I also would like to know how to reset the dropdowns if there chosen as well I cannot get a good grasp on this syntax I guess :/ `$("#div12 > .clearfix input:select").val("");` Where am I going wrong?

```js
function showhideCOREForm(transferring_vehicle_license) {
     if (transferring_vehicle_license == "Current") {
         document.getElementById("div11").style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById("div12").style.display = 'none';
   $("#div12 > #secondYearCB").prop("checked", false);
         FC.wantsASecondYear = false;
     } else if (transferring_vehicle_license == "Expired") {
         document.getElementById("div12").style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById("div11").style.display = 'none';
   $("#div6 > .clearfix input:text").val("");
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="Current" name="transferring_vehicle_license" id="transferring_vehicle_license" required="yes" onclick="calculateTotal()" onchange="showhideCOREForm(this.value);"/><label for="transferring_vehicle_license">Current Registration</label>
  <input type="radio" value="Expired" name="transferring_vehicle_license" id="notransferring_vehicle_license" onclick="calculateTotal()" onchange="showhideCOREForm(this.value);"/><label for="notransferring_vehicle_license">Expired Registration</label>

<div id="div12" style="display:none">

 <div class="clearfix">
  <label for='CMonths' class="labelDoubleIndent">Calculate Months:</label>
  <select name="month1" id="month1" size="1">
      <option value="">Choose a Month</option>
      <option value="0">January</option>
      <option value="1">February</option>
      <option value="2">March</option>
      <option value="3">April</option>
      <option value="4">May</option>
      <option value="5">June</option>
      <option value="6">July</option>
      <option value="7">August</option>
      <option value="8">September</option>
      <option value="9">October</option>
      <option value="10">November</option>
      <option value="11">December</option>
  </select>
  <select name="month2" id="month2" size="1">
      <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
  </select>
  <select name="month3" id="month3" size="1">
      <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
  </select>

  <div id="secondYear" class="labelDoubleIndent">
         <b>Do you want to add a second year?</b>
         Yes: <input type="checkbox" name="secondYear" id="secondYearCB" />
     </div><!-- secondYear -->
 </div>
</div>

<div id="div11" style="display:none">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using just wrong selector: the `#secondYearCB` is not a first child of `#div12`. Use descendant selector instead:

```
$('#div12 #secondYearCB').prop("checked", false);
```

The same reason is for `select` - select is not input! Use just:

```
$("#div12 > .clearfix select").val("");
```

Answer (score 3):

Both selectors are wrong to the CHECKBOX and SELECT.

Checkbox, as you are using an ID in it, just use the ID:

```
$("#secondYearCB").prop("checked", false);
```

The Selects, they are not INPUT, so use only the "select" word.

```
$("#div12 > .clearfix > select").val("");
```

P.s.: I add ">" to get only the direct SELECT childs inner the ".clearfix" div, if you don't want this, just remove it.

[Selector: >](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_parent_child.asp)

Comment: You changed more than just the way the element was being queried, which makes it work. If you just substitute what you answered into his current code it does not work.

Comment: @Aweary, yes but I do not changed the HTML, I just changed the way that the event is being dispached, if you test the Roland answer it will not work too, its not our problem, its from stack snippet maybe. :)

Comment: You did remove the `onchange` and `onclick` events, which I think was the right move here. I agree, I think stack snippet is having trouble with that.

Comment: So no problems, post your answer. For me the selectors are the wrong thing here, test by your self. Now why this is not working on stack snippet I don't know yet.

Comment: If you want to see with your own eyes, you can see here, the same JS and HTML with just my changes... http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/8adoy0pq/2/

Comment: Right, I think stack snippets is simply having an issue with it for some reason.